# Why does this code lead to an access violation?

Tags: c++, inheritance, boost, sdl

This function works perfectly fine, or so the compiler/debugger tells me

```
void GUIManager::init(ToScreen* tS)
{
    toScreen = tS;
    loadFonts();
    GUI_Surface = SDL_SetVideoMode( toScreen->width, toScreen->height, 32, SDL_SWSURFACE );
    components.push_back(&PlainText("Hello, World!", font, -20, -40));

}
```

In here, the first function call raises an access violation error.
The debugger doesn't show any problems.
I don't get the chance to debug components[0], since the program halts here.

```
void GUIManager::draw() 
{
    // This line here is the problem
    components[0].draw(GUI_Surface);
    // This line here is the problem


    SDL_BlitSurface(GUI_Surface, NULL, toScreen->Screen_Surface, NULL);
}
```

In case it's needed, this is my 'components'

```
boost::ptr_vector<GUIComponent> components;
```

Just let me know if any other code is needed. Perhaps that of PlainText, or GUIComponent

Comment: Just check that number of elements in `components` is not zero before drwaing.

Comment: components[0].position.x += 1; passes just fine.

Comment: You are pushing the address of a local variable into components. Given this memory has been freed any later access to it might result in an access violation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of pushing pointer to temporary, which ends its lifetime just after this line:

```
components.push_back(&PlainText("Hello, World!", font, -20, -40));
```

You should push dynamic object, which will exist as long as `components`:

```
components.push_back(new PlainText("Hello, World!", font, -20, -40));
```

See doc: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/ptr_sequence_adapter.html#modifiers

```
void push_back( T* x ); 
    Requirements: x != 0 
    Effects: Inserts the pointer into container and takes ownership of it
    Throws: bad_pointer if x == 0
    Exception safety: Strong guarantee
```

Comment: It's worth noting that `boost::ptr_vector` manages the deletion of the object later, unlike, say, `std::vector`.

Comment: @Dynguss true - added full doc.

Comment: Thank you greatly. Solved the issue successfully. Also, I'll certainly be looking into that documentation.